# Python Keyword association blank results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to build a sample data set where I can find frequent word
associations. I'm able to get to the point of tokenization of the words, but my word associator comes up blank. The code is attached as a reference along with the dataset being used appended at the end.

> Here is my code
>
> ```
> import pandas as pd 
> import nltk from nltk.tokenize 
> import word_tokenize from nltk.collocations 
> import BigramAssocMeasures,BigramCollocationFinder 
> from nltk.corpus import stopwords 
> import string
>
> # Load the CSV file into a Pandas DataFrame
>
> df = pd.read_csv('mtsamples.csv')
>
> #clean the data
>
> df = df.dropna() df.isna().any()
>
> def remove_stopwords(text):
>     tokens = text.split()
>     filtered_tokens = [token for token in tokens if token.lower() not in stop_words]
>     return ' '.join(filtered_tokens)
>
> stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
>
> def remove_punctuation(text):
>     translator = str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation)
>     return text.translate(translator)
>
> df['transcription'] = df['transcription'].apply(remove_punctuation)
> df['transcription'] = df['transcription'].str.lower()
> df['transcription'] = df['transcription'].apply(remove_stopwords)
>
> df.head()
>
> # Get the keyword from the user
>
> keyword = input('Enter a keyword: ')
>
>
> # Tokenize the text data
>
> tokenized_text = [word_tokenize(text) for text in df['transcription']]
>
> # Create a BigramCollocationFinder object to find frequent bigrams
>
> finder = BigramCollocationFinder.from_documents(tokenized_text)
>
> # Set the association measure to frequency
>
> measures = BigramAssocMeasures()
>
> # Find the frequent bigrams that contain the keyword
>
> matching_bigrams = finder.nbest(measures.raw_freq, 10)
> matching_bigrams = [bigram for bigram in matching_bigrams if keyword
> in bigram]
>
> # Print the frequent bigrams
>
> print('Frequent bigrams:') for bigram in matching_bigrams:
>     print(' '.join(bigram))
> ```

[Here is the dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tboyle10/medicaltranscriptions?resource=download)

Comment: Works like a charm. E.g. for `patient`: `Frequent bigrams:
patient tolerated`

Comment: I used the word 'female' And my results came up blank.

Comment: female is not in the 10 most frequent bigrams

Comment: I think I'm going about this the wrong way. I want to enter in any word found in the transcription column and get the most frequent word associated with the key word. I think I'm going to start over.

Comment: try this line: `matching_bigrams = finder.score_ngrams(measures.raw_freq)` instead of the one calling `nbest`. Maybe you can use that as a start. `matching_bigrams` will then contain tuples consiting of the bigram and the frequency, which you can filter like `matching_bigrams = [bigram for bigram in matching_bigrams if keyword
in bigram[0]]`

Comment: So I did this. 
matching_bigrams = finder.score_ngrams(measures.raw_freq)
matching_bigrams = [bigram for bigram in matching_bigrams if keyword in bigram[0]]
matching_bigrams

and I got the tuples, I just need to find the most frequent. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: So I added this 
def Sort_Tuple(tup):
 
    # getting length of list of tuples
    lst = len(tup)
    for i in range(0, lst):
 
        for j in range(0, lst-i-1):
            if (tup[j][1] > tup[j + 1][1]):
                temp = tup[j]
                tup[j] = tup[j + 1]
                tup[j + 1] = temp
    return tup

tup = matching_bigrams
sorted_tup = Sort_Tuple(tup)

[tup[0] for tup in sorted_tup]

And I got a list, I think is workable